# Internet Explorer takes considerably more time to load than FireFox-- to the point where it actually freezes. How can I prevent this?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer, dotnetnuke, load-time

One of our main pages takes an immense amount of time to load in IE8 (have not tried IE7 or 6). It's so bad that IE actually freezes up for a few seconds while trying to load the page.

Firefox is perfectly fine...

I've tried a bunch of different things but I cannot figure out what it is.

It's not very js intensive, although we are using modules (platform is DNN) that may be using a lot of js.

here's the link: [One World United](http://www.oneworldunited.com/MyWorld/CustomerHome/tabid/822/Default.aspx)
username: matt
password: globalbuying

Could you please take a look at the page and try to analyze what it is and what we can do to fix it.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Tested it in IE8 standard, it hangs. Tried it on IE8 (64-bit), works like a charm.

Comment: Tested on IE7, it's faster and doesn't hang. What is it about IE8 standard that would make it hang...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the site with IE8 compatibility mode on, and then compatibility mode off?  If either of those works significantly better, you could try something like forcing IE7 standards mode:

http://www.thechoppr.com/blog/2009/04/07/force-ie7-standards-on-ie8/

Comment: Not a bad idea, it does load slightly faster in IE7, mostly just because instead of hanging and appearing all at once you can see each thing loading. Not as pretty, but still much better than having the browser freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to manipulate any divs with js before they are fully parsed? That will screw up IE but FireFox will process that just fine.

Comment: manipulate using js? No, not unless the modules are doing so. The only manipulation that's done is using css.

Answer (score 1):

Didnt take much time to load for me either. This has happened to me occasionally when I had an unclosed div that was somehow conflicting with some JavaScript that I had at the end of the HTML.

Comment: Good point, we've been making constant changes to the html, never thought to check for that. I'll take a look at our skins and see.

Answer (score 0):

well on my comp it took less than 5 seconds to load, did you test it on multiple computers or just one? if just one it could be an addin issue.

Comment: It's definitely reproducible, it hangs on my box using IE8.

Comment: We've tested it on two computers... both accessing the same router/model though, it may be that our internet connection is just slow? were you using IE8?

Comment: well if it's more than just us then that's important enough to look into it. Don't want people to get frustrated and leave our website because of it.